# ModX shopkeeper — как отредактировать письмо с заказом?

Tags: cms, modx

Приходит такое письмо после заказа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы название заказанных товаров было текстом, а не ссылкой (как в данном случае *Пицца вариант 3*).

Подскажите где что можно поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация](http://wiki.modx-shopkeeper.ru/doku.php?id=shk3_docs) гласит, что чанк, который отвечает за вывод строки товара в письме по умолчанию называется `orderDataRow`. Параметр соответственно - `&orderDataRowTpl`. Этот чанк и редактируйте, как вам требуется.